# Look & Feel - Pagelayouts and Site Templates

Tags: powershell, feature, site-collection, branding, windows-application

I recently ran into a rather unfortunate assignment. It regards the selection of pagelayouts and sitetemplates which subsites should be able to use.

As I'm supposed to change this for 20+ site collections, it will be quiet a mouthful, so I was wondering if there exists any way of programmatically handling this. All site collections have the same pagelayouts and sitetemplates installed, as we deployed the branding package containing these, globally a few days ago.

Could this be done through either a Farm feature, PowerShell, or even a Windows Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use powershell. The class is [PublishingWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms516707) in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing. It exposes various methods like SetAvailableWebTemplates, SetAvailablePageLayouts to acomplish the task.